# LSTM Autoencoder for pretraining with various lengths input sequences

Tags: deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network, sequences, autoencoder

I need some help to understand what is the best way to tackle my problem using deep learning.
I have in my database many unlabeled sequences and a few labeled sequences.
I want to retrieve the label of each labeled sequence.
The sequences have various lengths, and are usually very long.
So far I have thought about doing the following:

1. Use a LSTM autoencoder as a "pre training step" to learn a simplified representation of the sequences using the unlabeled data
2. Encode the labeled sequences using the same model
3. Use another model to retrieve the labeled data (either LSTM, SVM, ...) from the simplified representation

So here are is my question:

**How to handle the various lengths of the sequences?**

So far I have tried the following for the autoencoder part (using Keras backend Theano):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0, input_shape=(None,2)))
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape = (8785,2), return_sequences = True))
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape = (8785,2), return_sequences = True))
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape = (8785,2)))
model.add(RepeatVector(8785))
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape = (8785,2), return_sequences = True))
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape = (8785,2), return_sequences = True))
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape = (8785,2), return_sequences = True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(2)))
```

After having padded my sequences.
But I am not sure it is ok to do that since my test data (the labeled sequences) could be longer than the longest sequence of the train data (unlabeled sequences).

Useless to say, all of this is quite new to me and after looking at many articles/forums I kind of lost my way. I am also not sure it is the best way to handle such problem.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You could set input_shape of the LSTM to (None, 2) to let Keras decide the sequence length dynamically. This might be relevant to you: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/6776

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But if I use (None,2) as input_shape, I think I cannot use RepeatVector right? Or what argument should I pass to this function?